# Bash moving created file

Tags: bash, directory, mv

I have a script that creates a file, what is the best way to edit that script that it moves the newly created file into a folder one above the directory it will be put in?

Thanks

Comment: Do you store the name of the file somewhere in the script?

Comment: Yeah it creates the filename in the script as it is run monthly

Comment: Can you edit your post and put your script in it ? (I mean the code of it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a little bit on how you create the file, but supposing you had a variable that held the name of your file. Then you could use `dirname` to get the directory, and then `mv` to move it.

```
mv "$file" $(dirname "$file")/..
```

**Update**: Based on the OP's comment the exact line would look like the following.

```
mv "FileName$1" $(dirname "FileName$1")/..
```

Comment: It creates FileName$1 ($1 represents the date). So outputs a file FileNameMarch15 etc.

Comment: @Sean, Please accept the answer if it resolved your question.